# How to find all possible n-elements subsets of a set?

Tags: algorithm, collections, set, combinations, puzzle

For a set of `k`-elements, I need to find all possible `n`-element subsets `(n < k)`.

How should I approach this problem?

Just a suggestion will be helpful Thanks!

Comment: `How should I approach this problem.` Pen and paper works best when thinking about algorithms.

Comment: @user1315305 question marked -ve because wrong tags, question is typical for me as well

Comment: @user1315305 You're very welcome. This is usually my answer when I see about zero effort put in.

Comment: @user1315305 there is not good solution but [an old similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098248/how-to-generate-all-k-elements-subsets-from-an-n-elements-set-recursively-in-jav)

Comment: Please don't vote to close this question, its a good question from algorithm I am also looking for some answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw this in topcoder's algorithm tutorials.Take some time and understand how it works.

Iterate through all k-element subsets of {0, 1, … N-1}

```
   int s = (1 << k) - 1;
   while (!(s & 1 << N))
   {
     // do stuff with s
     int lo = s & ~(s - 1);       // lowest one bit
     int lz = (s + lo) & ~s;      // lowest zero bit above lo
     s |= lz;                     // add lz to the set
     s &= ~(lz - 1);              // reset bits below lz
     s |= (lz / lo / 2) - 1;      // put back right number of bits at end
   }
```

Comment: While it is usually extremely efficient, bit magic is a poor way to communicate algorithmic ideas.

Comment: @G.Bach: Probably better to communicate the algorithm that solves the problem quickly than the algorithm that solves the problem slowly.  Especially when you comment it so that it's comprehensible.  No?

Comment: @tmyklebu Sure, the algorithm with better complexity is preferable, and comments do help. But while I know what this code is supposed to achieve, I don't understand how it works.

Comment: @G.Bach: Did you try?  I'll read the code and the comments:  `lo` is the lowest set bit.  `lz` is the lowest unset bit above it.  Consequently, `lz / lo - 1` has only its lowest `log2(lz) - log2(lo)` bits set.  That's one too many, so pick off the low bit by dividing by two.  Set `lz`, clear everything below `lz`, then set the right number of bits at the bottom of the number.

Comment: Sorry for my question, but how can I use this code in practice? What does 's' stand for?

Comment: @user1315305: s is the bitmask that represents the current k-element subset.For example it could be "1000" which means first element is present, all others are absent.

Comment: I noticed that it doesn't work for example when k = 21, N = 40. Why?

Comment: That's because int can store only 32 bits.So for N>32, you need to use long long which can store 64 bits.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I will have to use BigInteger in Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When I needed to get all combinations (or subsets) of an ArrayList of Strings in Java, I used this method.

```
public static List<List<String>> powerset(ArrayList<String> list) {
        List<List<String>> ps = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        ps.add(new ArrayList<String>());

        // for every item in the original list
        for (String item : list) {
            List<List<String>> newPs = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

            for (List<String> subset : ps) {
                // copy all of the current powerset's subsets
                newPs.add(subset);

                // plus the subsets appended with the current item
                List<String> newSubset = new ArrayList<String>(subset);
                newSubset.add(item);
                newPs.add(newSubset);
            }

            // powerset is now powerset of list.subList(0, list.indexOf(item)+1)
            ps = newPs;
        }
        return ps;
}
```

It's an expensive operation and probably not the perfect solution for your situation. But if I were trying to come up with a solution quickly, I would do something along these lines. You can check to see if the `newSubset` was less than `n`, the size of the subsets you want, and only add `item` to it if it is less than `n`. This would stop you from generating subset greater than n. At the end, you could iterate through `ps` and remove any arraylist that is less than `n`. Again, this solution is in no way perfect....but it should do the trick

Comment: I like this combinatorial approach, and considering it's a power set you're constructing, it does not look too bad to me. But if the job is only to get the subsets with a fixed number of elements, constructing the power set is exponentially more expensive.

Comment: Unfortunately I run out of memory for subset size = 21, and set size = 60 so I have to find some better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence:
Set A is set of whole numbers less than 10.

Written As:

```
A={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

it is called listing or roster method